# CSV database column edit

Tags: database, csv

I usually have more code oriented questions, but I need help with a CSV database. Basically I need to change it's format to Fname;Lname;email. The problem is that I have 13000 rows and all of the data is in 1 column, the separator is ";". I used different CSV file editors and all of them put the data in 1 column, so I can't change the order of those columns... i cannot re-extract the data from the original database. So is there a fix to that, or am I screwed?

So I am starting with a CSV file, that has ";" between each data cell in each rows. So I open Excel 2016 and I do: data > from text > I find the CSV file > I click on delimited ";", start import on row 1, file origin: Windows (ANSI) > delimiter: ";" > column data format: "General" > finish. And I get all the data in 1 column...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you...

You could use excel and a vb macro to do the shuffling for you. Split by ';' and put each row in an array, shuffle, and then concatenate?

You can also change the column break when importing a csv in excel.

Comment: The problem is that when I use the "data" > "import text" > use ";" separator, I still get all the data in one column, so I can't edit it.

Comment: That's odd, in Excel 2016 I get the correct column separation. Find and replace ';' with ',' and try to re-import?

Comment: So I am starting with a CSV file, that has ";" between each data cell in each rows. So I open Excel 2016 and I do: data > from text > I find the CSV file > I click on delimited, start import on row 1, file origin: Windows (ANSI) > delimiter: ";" > column data format: "General" > finish. And I get all the data in 1 column...

Comment: What was the issue?